# iOS7 SDK force Landscape for viewController

Tags: ios, ios6

On iOS6 I had a method to make one view controller in my navigation-style app auto rotate to landscape when I pushed it. (Basically present a bogus view controller and dismiss it in viewWillAppear).

```
UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
if (![mVC isBeingDismissed])
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

With the latest SDK this no longer works.  Does anyone have another way to auto rotate?

Comment: Are you implement -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations method?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is simple, just pass YES to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

```
UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
if (![mVC isBeingDismissed])
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //Fix here
```

Answer (score 0):

[From Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

"When a view controller is presented over the root view controller, the system behavior changes in two ways. First, the presented view controller is used instead of the root view controller    when determining whether an orientation is supported. Second, the presented view controller can also provide a preferred orientation. If the view controller is presented full screen, the user interface is presented in the preferred orientation. The user is expected to see that the orientation is different from the device orientation and rotate the device. A preferred orientation is most often used when the content must be presented in the new orientation."

I think here you can use the preferred orientation method here.